# How to compare Lists of Guids in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, comparison

I have got this structure

```
var values = new Dictionary<int, List<Guid>>();
```

And I have to say if all dictionary elements has the same set of `List<Guid>`.

I dont need to know which are exactly are different, just to answer the question.

So it looks like

`List A { 1, 2, 3}  List B { 1, 2, 3}   List C { 1, 2, 3}` the same and have no difference.

and

`List A { 3, 2, 3}   List B { 1, 2, 3}   List C { 1, 2, 3}`  are not the same.

I have no clue where I can start it.

Initially i guessed to convert `List<Guid>` to `string` and just do `distinct` operation over it.

But is this a good approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Can your list contain the same guid multiple times? Does the order count?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes it can. Order count is not important.

Comment: @ClarkKent: When you say "Order count is not important" do you mean that the order is unimportant *and* the count is unimportant, so for example "A,B" is equal to "B,A,A"?

Comment: @krystanhonour I just updated my question. Take a look, pls.

Comment: That doesn't clarify things much... what about { 1, 2, 3 } and { 3, 3, 2, 1 }? Are they the same, in that they're both {1, 2, 3} just with potentially different orders and counts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd create a `HashSet<Guid>` from one of the values (any) and then check that all of the others are equal to it:

```
// TODO: Handle the dictionary being empty
var firstSet = new HashSet<Guid>(values.First().Value);
var allEqual = values.All(pair => firstSet.SetEquals(pair.Value));
```

This assumes that:

- The order within each list is unimportant
- The number of times each GUID appears in the list is unimportant

(i.e. you really are thinking of them as sets, not lists, at least for this part of the code)

In other words, if you have guids A and B, the code above assumes that { A, B, B } is equivalent to { B, A }.

Comment: [There can be repeated elements.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678469/how-to-compare-lists-of-guids-in-c-sharp#comment41956002_26678469)  This wouldn't handle that.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, but it's not clear whether that matters. The OP said "Order count is not important" which isn't as clear as it might be. I've updated my answer to clarify my assumptions, and asked the OP to clarify the question further.

Comment: Went to answer this with a foreach iteration but I like this much better, the only issue I can think of is whether or not the list being ordered the same will affect the hash value?

Comment: @PseudoNym01: The hash value of the set isn't used here - I'm using `SetEquals`.

Answer (score -1):

`SequenceEquals()` might be what you're looking for. Combine it with `IEnumerable.All()` and you can get a boolean answer whether all elements of your dictionary contain the same Lists. For instance:

```
values.All(list => values.All(list2 => list2.SequenceEquals(list));
```

Comment: That depends if order matters for the guids.  Since [it does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678469/how-to-compare-lists-of-guids-in-c-sharp#comment41956002_26678469) this answer is wrong.